# Getting IP Addresses range and subnet for AWS EC2

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, ip, subnet

I have an AWS EC2 instance that I'm running in the US-EAST OHIO region. But, I don't want to set `0.0.0.0/0` IP address in my inbound rules for the security group. So, I select: `SSH` -> `MyIP` to get the ip address every time I run the instance.

I want to understand how I can add a range of IP addresses instead?
For example, when I select `SSH` -> `Custom` instead of `MyIP`, and if I want to include all IP addresses that include the ranges `54.95.21.(any number here)`, how do I do that? i.e., the last number could be any number, it should allow that, first 3 should be fixed. Also, what should be the `subnet` for the range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`54.95.21.*` is expressed as `54.95.21.0/24`.

`x.x.x.x/y` is called [CIDR notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation).

The number after `/` is the number of masked bits.  `/24` is equivalent to the dotted-quad subnet mask of `255.255.255.0` (each 255 is 8 bits, 2^8-1 = 255, 8 + 8 + 8 + 0 = 24).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: Great! Thank you.